# Drupal 7 not sending e-mail after upgrade

Tags: php, email, drupal, upgrade

I've successfully upgraded my drupal website from v7.32 to v7.37. But after the upgrade I found that my website is not sending emails. I've checked the SMTP Authentication module and found that it could send test emails but the site won't send email. What could be the problem?

addon: I am using amazon aws ec2 instance with ses service

Comment: what does your error log tell you what error it is

Comment: the error log is not showing any error